# Laptop fan stopped working, but spins for one second after turning off PC

Tags: laptop, fan

I have Dell Latitude 5840. Yesterday I pressed "o" on the keyboard to hard. I heard some scratching sound and then silence. Basicaly my fan stopped working. I tired some monitoring software and all is showing 0 rotations. But Im sure the problem is not in mechanical damage of the fan. When I turn off the PC the fan spins for a second and then stops. What can be the issue?

Comment: Take it to service. Nothing that can be diagnosed on the web, no answer applicable here.

Comment: How you can be sure that the problem is not mechanical ? You probably hit the keyboard too high and this damaged a component of the motherboard.

Comment: im only sure it is not mechanical damage of the fan. because it is able to spin. it just spins at incorrect time.(at pc turn off instead of at pc startup)

Comment: Buy a new fan on eBay - they're far less expensive than paying for service _(fan will likely be <$20)_. Fans use PWM, so from the symptoms reported, it sounds like the fan's motor was impeded, frying a component on the fan's PCB or damaging something in the motor. You can determine this for sure by running the onboard hardware diagnostics that are accessible from the UEFI boot options or possibly from within the UEFI firmware settings. Until you have a working fan, the laptop should not be used, or you risk damaging the motherboard components that fan is cooling, especially if it's the CPU fan

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ Replacing the fan is super simple and Dell usually provides a disassembly manual for the laptops that show each step in order for the component needing to be replaced. Replacing laptop components requires no prior knowledge - no service tech needed, unless it's covered under warranty, as it only requires a torx screwdriver =]

Comment: If the fan spins, it's likely not broken. More likely, a cable was pulled loose, or a surface-mount component was knocked off the PCB by excessive pressure -- fixable by a *proficient* electronic technician.